# Angularjs Angular-Material Back Button Executes Twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, material-design, event-propagation

I just incorporated angular-material v1.1.20 into my angularjs v1.3.13 project and now, only when running on a mobile device and pressing the back button, the back operation is executed twice. When investigating the call stack during debug I notice that the angular back button eventHandler is called twice in a row as shown in the screenshot below. Any idea how to stop this from happening?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I was able to fix this event propagation issue by simply modifying `angular-material.js` (v1.1.20) and adding the following:

```js
4095 eventObj.srcEvent = srcEvent;
     + eventObj.immediatePropagationStopped = true;
4096
4097 angular.extend(eventObj, {
...
4166 eventObj.srcEvent = srcEvent;
     + eventObj.immediatePropagationStopped = true;
4167 eventPointer.target.dispatchEvent(eventObj);
```

Or by running the following find and replace regular expression:

**Find** - `eventObj\.\$material = true;\n    eventObj\.pointer = eventPointer;\n    eventObj\.srcEvent = srcEvent;`

**Replace** - `$0\n    eventObj.immediatePropagationStopped = true;`

`angular-material.min.js` can also be modified by running the following find and replace regular expression:

**Find** - `\$material=!0,o\.pointer=n,o\.srcEvent=e,`

**Replace** - `$0o.immediatePropagationStopped=!0,`